# cordova serve vs phonegap serve commands

Tags: cordova

Phonegap just released an app http://app.phonegap.com/ which listens to the port that runs when using:

```
phonegap serve
```

I know that you can also run:

```
cordova serve
```

but the major difference is **phonegap serve** continually *refreshes* content while **cordova serve** seems to be only *static*.

Does anyone know if it's possible to run the **cordova serve** command and have it continually refresh the content like **phonegap serve** does?

Comment: not currently. this functionality was just released yesterday, I am sure it will roll over to the cordova cli in time.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It's been tough for me to decide which cli to use!  For awhile I was using phonegap, but I just recently switched over to using pure cordova when I started getting some errors building with phonegap.  I suppose either one can work...

Comment: The `phonegap` cli is meant to be used with the `cordova` cli unless you are only doing remote builds. Think of it as extending the `cordova` cli adding the remote build capabilities, and now the continuous serve capabilities.

Comment: Ok, that kind of helps - I think my frustration is that if I use cordova to create my project *cordova create...* then I'm no longer able to use the phonegap CLI to do anything else, such as *phonegap server*.

Comment: If you created the project with cordova CLI and want to use your project with phonegap CLI, changing just the `<widget>` namespace in config.xml should be enough : xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"

Comment: and thanks about the serve command I haden't seen this info yet.

Comment: No problem!  Just happened to hear about the *serve* command while browsing twitter.  As for your comment - it still didn't work when I changed the namespace, but what did make it work was copying the .cordova folder from another phonegap project into the root of my cordova project.  That made it work without even having to change the namespace, which was nice!  Thanks for helping me get going in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

After you've created a project using Cordova, you can serve it with Phonegap using the hack described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151325/error-project-directory-could-not-be-found-with-phonegap)

In short, create a throwaway project using phonegap, then import the .cordova directory from it into your Cordova project.

Answer (score 0):

To make the content refresh with Cordova, you need to use GapReload : 
https://github.com/fingerproof/cordova-plugin-gapreload

it implements the livereload autorefresh system for mobile apps (emulated or real devices)

Comment: IDE like [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) do it as well when you enable **Live Preview** `Ctrl+Alt+P` option.

Answer (score 0):

(npm packages : livereload, phonegap, ionicframework)

Live Reload npm plugin:
Live reload browser extensions might be one of the good solution I guess.

OR

make project into phonegap or ionic framework project 
(Just move www folder and config.xml)

1. Create new project using phone gap or ionic framework.
2. replace www folder and config.xml in project directory.
3. then use phone gap server or ionic serve.

Ref :

http://livereload.com/extensions/

https://github.com/napcs/node-livereload

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/4-run-your-app/cli/