# error: project directory could not be found - with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, web-applications, development-environment

I want to use the [PhoneGap Developer App](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/) for my project. I updated my PhoneGap version on my Mac to the newest version with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Then I `cd`ed to my project folder (root folder) and entered the command `phonegap serve`, but everything I get is an `[error] project directory could not be found`. When I create a completely new project, than everything works fine, but why can't I use that Developer App with my current project?

Comment: was your current project created with `cordova` or `phonegap`?

Comment: wow, good question. i don't know, didn't thought there is much of a difference (besides the name), but i think cordova (i have some cordova folder in my project)... can i update it to phonegap?

Comment: to run `phonegap` commands the project has to be created with `phonegap`. Do this: Create a new project with `phonegap`, copy `www` and `config.xml` from your existing project into the new project. You will also have to install any plugins needed in the new project.

Comment: fun fact is that even the **phonegap** get-startet-documentation refers to **cordova** commands ([see here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)). because of that and other hints i thought phonegap and cordova are compeletely the same (just renamed after a while). the documentation is really bad and faulty.

Comment: but thanks for your help. i made a new (phonegap) project and copied the `config.xml` and `www` to the folder. but how should i add the plugins? with `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`? because i can't find another command in the phonegap documentation...

Comment: Yes, use `cordova plugin add`. Here is an explanation of Cordova vs. PhoneGap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569459/why-does-cordovas-documentation-page-look-similar-to-phonegaps-documentation-p/23570095#23570095

Comment: thank you. when you make your comment to an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the project was created with `cordova` it will be easiest to create a new project with `phonegap` and then copy over the `www` and `config.xml` from the existing project. You will also have to add the plugins to this new project but still use `cordova plugin add` to do so.

Comment: `PhoneGap` is looking for is a hidden directory called `.cordova` containing a file called `config.json`. Copying them from another project created with `phonegap create` (or creating them manually) is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

The `phonegap` commands create a hidden directory at the root of the app called `/.cordova`

You can move this directory into your existing app created with `cordova` to enable `phonegap serve`

`mv /app-created-with-phone-gap/.cordova /app-create-with-cordova/`

Answer (score 2):

I've already come back with this question twice so I'll add my own answer that's slightly faster for me than creating another solution and copying the `.cordova` directory.

**From your project root:**

1. `mkdir .cordova`
2. Create a file called `config.json` with the following contents

   ```
   {
       "lib": {
           "www": {
               "id": "com.phonegap.helloworld",
               "version": "3.5.0",
               "uri": "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/3.5.0.tar.gz"
           }
       }
   }
   ```

**You don't even have to modify the contents of the file.

`$ phonegap serve` now works.

For the 'right' answer though that's more likely to work with future versions of cordova/phonegap, follow the answer of BZMWillemsen.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the sample project with version 5.0.0-0.27.1 did not create the `.cordova` directory, so I didn't add one to my project.

Renaming the project asset directory to `www` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same but the project that it couldn't find was the default "hello world", it re-downloaded it when I created a new project as per Dawson's answer. After that my original project worked fine.

Comment: `.cordova/config.json `

{
    "lib": {
        "www": {
            "id": "com.phonegap.helloworld",
            "version": "3.5.0",
            "uri": "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/3.5.0.tar.gz"
        }
    }