# cordova-plugin-file in Chrome: cordova is not defined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I use cordova-plugin-file in my ionic app to download images and save to local.

When I run it in emulator or iphone, there is no error, but when I test it in Chrome, it says,  `cordova is not defined` when I try to access `cordova.file.dataDirectory`

How can I run cordova-plugin-file in chrome?

Comment: cordova has a `browser` platform which enables you to test certain features in the browser.

Comment: Could you please more specific?

Comment: Check [this blog](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/09/24/Browser-as-a-platform-for-your-PhoneGapCordova-apps) - I haven't used it myself so I can't help you any further.

Comment: @Sato: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No, I tried your method, it does not work.

Comment: You cannot run that plugin in the browser. You can get rid of the error though.

Comment: If we remove the cordova.js file from index.html - to make it work for browsers - do we have to add it back in again for iOS/Android builds to work?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Cordova will not be available in the browser; only on your device.

In your **index.html** you should have this script reference:

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

As the note says, the script won't be available during the development.
It will be replaced during the build process.

You can try it yourself:

```
cordova platform add android
```

then

```
cordova build
```

and you should find under `platforms\android\assets\www` 2 js files: **cordova.js** and **cordova_plugins.js**.

Another option is to add browser as platform:

```
cordova platform add browser
```

and the run it:

```
cordova run browser
```

but you might face a few troubles.

Comment: How to develop when file is not supported by browsers?

Comment: @ArturKeyan: Glad I've helped. Cheers.

Comment: Where do you run "cordova platform add browser"?

Answer (score 0):

What you easily could do is copy cordova.js yourself to your root directory for testing.The file resides e.g in the directory

> cordova-project/platforms/ios/platform_www

You could easily just copy it over.
If you do it the cordova object is available and can be accessed in your code e.g.

```
cordova.file.dataDirectory
```

A good approach for debugging and testing Cordova applications is the Cordova browser plugin in conjunction with Phonegap installed to get access to the

```
phonegap serve browser
```

command. That way you can conveniently test your application right on your computer and don't have to send it to your device. It needs to be said that above mentioned cordova.file.dataDirectory is not available on your computer. Some plugins provide proxies for the browser platform that you could test them in your browser, too. 
For me the good thing with phonegap serve browser is when you edit your code and save it and then reload your browser the change get reflected.

I have to mention one more point to get the code changes reflection working.You have to create a

> .cordova

directory inside your Cordova project root folder. Then you have to add a
config.json file inside with following content:

```
{
"lib": {
    "www": {
        "id": "com.phonegap.helloworld",
        "version": "3.5.0",
        "uri": "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/3.5.0.tar.gz"
    }
}
}
```

As stated in following post from SO:
[Get phone gap serve working in Cordova project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25518576/1390502)

Comment: I just realized that it might be nonsense to copy cordova.js over. Sure you get access to e.g. the defined properties (as the dataDirectory property I mentioned) but it would be no benefit since (as I also wrote) that property is not defined on desktop. My regard was just to test the File API and you do not need the Cordova object for that. Nevertheless I do not delete my entry because the last part regarding debugging Cordova applications maybe is helpful for someone since it is a collection of steps necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this alternate pluggin instead cordova-plugin-file-transfer.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

instead of:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

You can do this

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, successCallback, errorCallback);
```