# Ionic not founding cordova.js

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

When I `ionic serve`, my main page console shows me this error:

```
ng-cordova-beacon.js:53 Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
at Object.requestWhenInUseAuthorization (ng-cordova-beacon.js:53)
at app.js?ionicCachebuster=10643:25
at Array.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js?ionicCachebuster=10643:56238)
at onPlatformReady (ionic.bundle.js?ionicCachebuster=10643:2496)
at onWindowLoad (ionic.bundle.js?ionicCachebuster=10643:2477)
```

But in the html's page there is:

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js?ionicCachebuster=10643"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
**<script src="cordova.js"></script>**
<script src="js/ng-cordova-beacon.js"></script>
```

Anyone can help me? ;)

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31368993/6921903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova is not available on browser(as you can see in html file, cordova will be 404 during developmet). If you are using any cordova plugins or ionic native plugins, you have to test that application in real device.

**Android:**

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
ionic run android
```

**ios:**

```
ionic platform add ios
ionic build ios
ionic run ios
```

Comment: If we remove the cordova.js file from index.html - to make it work for browsers - do we have to add it back in again for iOS/Android builds to work?

Comment: WhY to remove cordova.js ??