# Cordova run vs serve

Tags: cordova, single-page-application

I'm trying to understand the difference between those two commands.
I'm developing an app for both browser and iOs.

When I do : `cordova run browser`, it will open a new Chrome window with my app available at `http://localhost:8000`

and when I do `cordova serve` I can see all my platforms at `http://localhost:8000/` , and my browser app at : `http://localhost:8000/browser/www` which get my app router confused because of the `/browser/www`.

Can someone explain the difference between them ? I read that `serve` is for static files, but `run` will also works...

Comment: May be you can have a look here:   [**cordova serve vs phonegap serve commands**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23158577/5737774)